# ReactJS this.setState() out of sync with this.state.myvar

Tags: reactjs

In this ReactJS code in component  I would expect `this.setState( {b_MyPartyCat: value} )` to update `this.state.b_MyPartyCat` so the two console.log statements in `updatePartyCategory()` show the same value, but they don't.

```
var MyIconButton = React.createClass({

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var b_buttonOn = false;
    if (this.props.pressed === true) {
      b_buttonOn = false;
    }
    else {
      b_buttonOn = true;
    }
    this.props.updateFilter( b_buttonOn ); 
  },

  render: function() {   
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="image" src={this.props.pressed ? this.props.onpic : this.props.offpic }></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var MyPartyCatButton = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <MyIconButton pressed={this.props.pressed} updateFilter={this.props.updateFilter} onpic="static/images/icon1.jpeg" offpic="static/images/off-icon.jpg"/>
    );
  }
});

//
// Main App view
var MyHomeView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    // This is where I'll eventually get data from the server.
    return {
      b_MyPartyCat: true
    };
  },

  updatePartyCategory: function(value) {
    // Eventually will write value to the server.
    this.setState( {b_MyPartyCat: value} );

    console.log("INSIDE: MyHomeView() updatePartyCategory() value = " + value );
    console.log("INSIDE: MyHomeView() updatePartyCategory() this.state.b_MyPartyCat = " + this.state.b_MyPartyCat );

  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
         <MyPartyCatButton pressed={this.state.b_MyPartyCat} updateFilter={this.updatePartyCategory}/>
        </div>

        // Eventually will have 3 other categories i.e. Books, Skateboards, Trees !
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`setState` actually queues a state update.  If you want to do something after it's actually executed, you can pass a callback as the second argument.

```
updatePartyCategory: function(value) {
    this.setState({b_MyPartyCat: value}, function(){
        console.log(this.state.value === value); // true
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: Got it thanks, that's what I suspected, but didn't think about callbacks, I'm still wearing my C++ hat. I'll use `value` to keep it simple without needing the  callback, but this is good to know, just in case !-) http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: Is this absolutely required too `.bind(this)`, what happens without the .bind? I can't tell the difference when I try with or without .bind.

Comment: @GiantElk: In [typical JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) you do, with [React's Autobinding](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation) you don't! :-)

Comment: Well if removing .bind still has it working, then it must be calling it in that context.  I tracing through the source after watching the component and state change object passed through 7 functions and 3 files :-)

Comment: Yes, the callback is intentionally called with the component as context.

Comment: With ES6 you do not need `.bind(this)` instead use `this.setState({b_MyPartyCat: value}, ()=>{
        console.log(this.state.value === value); // true
    });`