# ReactJS concurrent SetState race condition

Tags: reactjs, race-condition, setstate

I have a component structure like this

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C/>
        <C/>
    </B>
    <D>
       <E/>
       <E/>
    </D>
</A>
```

Idea is that actions on components in block E are processed by a function of component A to state of A and than passed down to B and C as props. I know, that better way was to use Flux, pubsub-js or other Store-message system, but hope if someone can explain why correct to the best of my understanding solution doesn't work.

Calling this function of component A simalteneously from multiple instances of component E leads to race condition with only one change in state (instead of each function call providing a change)

```
updateState(value,index){
   this.setState(update(this.state, {
        a: {
          [index]: {
            b: {
             $set: value
            }
          }
        }
    })
);
}
```

Function update here comes from

```
import update from 'react/lib/update';
```

Bad solution that goes against ReactJS reccomended practices, but works well:

```
updateState(value,index){
   this.state.a[index].b=value;
   this.forceUpdate();
);
}
```

My question is:

Is it a bug, that multiple simalteneous setState invokes a race condition, or I'm doing something wrong without understnding it?

Comment: setState is meant to be asynchronous, and is batched by React whenever possible for performance

Comment: You may also want to send a callback http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172850/reactjs-this-setstate-out-of-sync-with-this-state-myvar

Answer (score 47):

You probably want to pass a function to `setState` which should remove such race conditions. Something like:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    someProp: prevState.someProp + 1,
  };
});
```

Even if two different parts of your application do this at the same time, both functions will still be called and `someProp` will be incremented twice.

If you were to do this instead: `this.setState({someProp: this.state.someProp + 1})` it could only be incremented once because `this.state.someProp` isn't updated directly after calling `setState`. But when passing a function to `setState` you get the previous state as an argument, which lets you avoid data races.

Comment: I believe that `update` function should do exactly the same. To clarify - in my case I do access different properties of complex state object overwriting them.

Comment: You shouldn't change the object that is passed in to that function. You should return a new object with the change state instead. And the parameter is called `prevState` not `currentState` which also hints at that.

Comment: What the hell just happened ? :D That was amazing thank you

Answer (score 12):

According to React documentation, as mentioned in the first answer, you can pass a function to ensure the atomicity's operation. The thing is that you should not modify the state but return the new value inside the passed function:

```
setState(function(previousState, currentProps) {
  return {myInteger: previousState.myInteger + 1};
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html