# this.setState() does not work in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

I have a login page in which I am using `componentWillReceiveProps` to route to the next page. But the `state` that I am setting inside `componentWillReceiveProps` does not seem to set.

This is my `componentWillReceiveProps` method :

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.isAuthenticated === true) {
          browserHistory.push('/home');
      } else {
        console.log("this.props :::" + JSON.stringify(this.props))
          console.log("this.state :::" + JSON.stringify(this.state))
          console.log("nextProps :::" + JSON.stringify(nextProps))
          this.setState({
              errorMessage: nextProps.authenticationError
          })
          console.log("this.state :::" + JSON.stringify(this.state))
      }
  }
```

The `console output` I am getting is this :

```
this.props :::{"authenticationError":null}  
this.state :::{"username":"35135","password":"3135","errorMessage":""}  
nextProps :::{"isAuthenticated":false,"authenticationError":"Could not find user in DB."}  
this.state :::{"username":"35135","password":"3135","errorMessage":""}
```

Here even after setting the state, my state has not changed.

Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT:** I have this component which is `ErrorText` , which takes in the `errroMessage` property.

```
<ErrorText errorMsg={this.state.errorMessage}></ErrorText>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`setState()` is an asynchronous operation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate), so it doesn't take effect immediately:

> `setState()` **enqueues** changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state [...]
>
> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) or a `setState` callback [...], either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

Here's an example of a `setState` callback in your context:

```
this.setState(
    { errorMessage: nextProps.authenticationError },
    function() {
        console.log( 'this.state ::: ' + JSON.stringify( this.state ) );
    }
);
```

Comment: if I use, `componentDidUpdate`, will it again render the component ?

Comment: You should check the new state in `componentDidUpdate` or in the `render`. The general meaning is: just after calling `setState` the state is not updated.

Comment: Actually my use case is this : if my user is found, I redirect, if not I will set the error message in my state. I am sure that `componentWillReceiveProps` will do render again. But I want to know if `componentDidUpdate` update will do `render` by itself, or should I use `forceUpdate()` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, read the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 1):

Refer to same stackoverflow question:

[Why Calling react setState method doesnt mutate the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because this.setState is an async function. You can pass a callback to handle events which should happen directly after setting state. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172850/reactjs-this-setstate-out-of-sync-with-this-state-myvar?rq=1) chosen answer for a code example.